# SF integration : Response XML expected is different

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api

We need to send a custom Response (that holds Account and Contact info),where in these two entities needs to be present at a single level and not as a  parent - child relationship.

How shall i change the structure of Response XML,to fullfill this requirement.
Can we achieve this without the help of any code?

Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: @JimRae : It might be a basic question, but  am new to integration and dont know,how to go about it. What would you suggest for this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you create your own Apex web service (a code based solution).  This allows you to structure the result in a format that you choose and that you can control.  You said in your question that the response was not in the format you expected, but did not share how you were making your request.  If you are limited to using only the standard services (REST or SOAP) then you will be limited to a single object or at best a hierarchy of related objects.

Comment: what be your advice on this.  I am able to test and see the result of webservice query operation on salesforce. But am not able to figure out how shall i handle the case of failure. Eg: if it follows an exception path--then it should send a NACK to external system -with fault message and reason to rectify. or show internal error to me to rectify it.